# how to install haskell openid package in windows

Tags: windows, haskell, openid, openssl

haskell 'openid' package depends on HsOpenSSL and nano-hmac packages which requires openssl. I've compiled openssl for MinGW in C:\OpenSSL\ directory and installed openid package with following command:

```
cabal install openid --extra-include-dirs=C:\OpenSSL\outinc --extra-lib-dirs=C:\OpenSSL\out
```

When I'm trying to compile haskell program using this package I'm receiving lots linking errors.

test.hs:

```
import Network.OpenID

main = print "ok"
```

`ghc --make test.hs`:

```
Linking test.exe ...
C:\OpenSSL\out/libcrypto.a(m_sha1.o):m_sha1.c:(.text+0x60): multiple definition of `EVP_sha1'
C:\OpenSSL\out/libeay32.a(deegs01228.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
C:\OpenSSL\out/libcrypto.a(m_sha1.o):m_sha1.c:(.text+0x100): multiple definition of `EVP_sha256'
C:\OpenSSL\out/libeay32.a(deegs01230.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
.....
C:\OpenSSL\out/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:(.text+0x2d4): undefined reference to `X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_purpose'
C:\OpenSSL\out/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:(.text+0x2f1): undefined reference to `X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_purpose'
C:\OpenSSL\out/libssl.a(ssl_lib.o):ssl_lib.c:(.text+0x314): undefined reference to `X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_trust'
.....
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there may be a version mismatch somewhere. Try using the precompiled binaries for OpenSSL here: http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html

I was able to get the instructions here to work with the latest version of HsOpenSSL: http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Builder (in fact I worked with the maintainer to make these instructions work without needing to patch the package.)